# Taking a special image derivative using convolution

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, convolution

I have two images at different times. The first image is `im1` at time `t1` and the second image is `im2` at time `t2`. I want to take the spatial derivative with respect to `x`. Could someone help me understand the following `MATLAB` code?

```
fx = conv2(im1, 0.25 * [-1 1; -1 1]) + conv2(im2,  0.25 *[-1 1; -1 1]);
```

I would be thankful to if someone can shed light on this kernel.

[image]

What type of image derivative the above mentioned code is? Is my understanding of what the kernel does correct, shown below?

[image]

where superscripts `n` and `n+1` represent time `t1` and `t2`, respectively. `i` loops through the rows (vertical) and `j` loops through the columns (horizontal) of the image function `f`, as shown in figure below.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The convolution is done by multiplying a window of 2x2 pixels with the kernel and summing up the result. 
Since the first term in each row is -1 and the second is 1, the convolution result for each pixel will be the difference between two adjacent horizontal pixels, which is a (discrete) derivative in the horizontal direction.